# Caching NHibernate DetachedCriteria in second-level cache

Tags: c#, nhibernate, caching

I'm interesting in following: does NHibernate support DetachedCriteria caching? I found a lot of examples but no one with DetachedCriteria.

--
Thanks, 
Kiryl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get results from a `DetachedCriteria`, you first have to `GetExecutableCriteria()`.

That's what you'll cache; everything you've seen about caching Criteria applies here.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell NH to cache the results of a Query whether that be from Detached or Attached criteria AFAIK.

Could you be more specific or show some code?